# Add new column in a dataset based on dataset

Tags: r, loops

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("LLOY.L",
           from = datefrom,
           to = dateto,
           auto.assign = TRUE)
LLOY.L$MovingAverages <- 0
e <- movavg(LLOY.L$LLOY.L.Close, 5, type = c("e"))
LLOY.L[, 7] <- e
```

Is there a way to create a new column of this dataset that means if column 4 is greater than column 7 it prints "Buy Stock" in each row, else print "Sell Stock", I have tried using loops with no success

Comment: Please add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610). Also show what you have already tried.That way you can help others to help you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do it using `ifelse` function in R.

```
df$new_var <- ifelse(df[, 4] > df[, 7], "Buy Stock", "Sell Stock")
```

where `df` is your dataset, in which you want create new column.

I hopes, it helps you.